# Ternary Operator and lazy evaluation

Tags: lazy-evaluation

Is ternary operator an example of lazy evaluation?
If we assume a code snippet like: 
Variable = Condition ? function1(param) : function2(param);
Can it be an example of lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most languages - yes, it is evaluated lazily. However it does not necessarily the situation. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

> Note that some languages may evaluate 'both' the true- and
>   false-expressions, even though only one or the other will be assigned
>   to the variable. This means that if the true- or false-expression
>   contain a function call, that function may be called and executed
>   (causing any related side-effects due to the function's execution),
>   regardless of whether or not its result will be used.

For example, in Delphi it is not lazily evaluated:

> Unlike a true ternary operator however, both of the results are
>   evaluated prior to performing the comparison. For example, if one of
>   the results is a call to a function which inserts a row into a
>   database table, that function will be called whether or not the
>   condition to return that specific result is met.